# Android Studio shuts down forcefully

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having a good problem with Android Studio. Initially I was using eclipse to develop android App, but eclipse display funny stuffs like deleting all my codes and most times crashes so I decided to try Android Studio.

Now am using android studio, but whenever I open an activity to start typing code, the IDE forcefully shuts down. Initially i tougth this happens when there is an error in your code, because I had an instance where the IDE shut down, was fixed by correcting the errors. But now the codes are all correct and when I install on emulator it installs properly.

But whenever I open an Activity and start to type Android Studio shuts down. I have tried to check for similar question, but could not find anything suitable. Please I need your help because I have a lot of project with deadlines and this AS behaviour is making me run nuts.. Thanks

Comment: Not the biggest fan of eclipse, but I'm pretty sure that if it would randomly delete code fewer people would use it. Regarding Android Studio: Check the logs and see what it complains about. Also, make sure you are on the latest version.

Comment: @Jan groth Thanks for your quick response. I checked the logs no complains. This only hapens when I open an Activity if i open manifest, layout or ordinary java class nothing happens but whenever I open an Activity it shuts down

Comment: You sure you checked the **Android Studio logs**? I would be very surprised if AS shut down without a hint in its log files...

Comment: On *toolbar -> Help Menu -> Show log in explorer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all I finally got the solution to the shutdown. I had to create all the Activity used from AS and copy the codes into each file created. Initially i copied all the Activities, resources and Manifest I created in eclipse and paste them into AS. I guess AS doesn't perform auto update and this cause it not have have reference of the pasted files in memory making it to crash.

Answer (score 3):

There might be memory issue with Android Studio. I recommend you to shutdown all the heavy-weight memory consuming application like Chrome etc. to be shutdown.
I hope it will help.

Comment: I tried closing all the App as you've said but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Uninstall it and install a new one.. Can u tell me about your PCs configuration?

Comment: Windows 8, core i7 8GB RAM

Comment: Thats a superb configuration!! Just try reinstalling it. Hope it helps.Else.. revert back to eclipse as AS is still to be perfected.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some plugins keep running if studio crashes and they consume so much memory that studio is not able to launch again.

Or see if other applications are running and consuming much memory.

Or you can restart the system.